Mailchimp dynamic property error on constructor for MailchimpMarketing apiClient
We are using Mailchimp 3.0.0 on a drupal 10 site, with php 8.2.
We have a service that sends an email to a distribution list using Mailchimp. We use a Mailchimp campaign to do this in a service class php file.
In this file we have:
   use MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient;

class EmailSender {
   public function sendEmails () {

   $client = new ApiClient();  // Fails on this line
   }
}

We are getting about 20 errors that the constructor is creating a dynamic property.
It is known that dynamic property creation is deprecated in php 8.2.
These properties include: $accountExport, $accountExports, $activityFeed, $authorizedApps, $automations, $batchWebHooks, etc
We believe we are using the most recent version of Mailchimp.
What can we do to eliminate these errors?
Thank you

The code you cannot be causing the error as it is not creating a dynamic property in the code you showed. Your best bet is to open a ticket in the module issue queue.

In future, show the actual error with the stack trace.

Thank you -- Yes, the problem is happening in the Mailchimp module itself. Perhaps Mailchimp 3.0.0 simply does not work with php 8.2. Drupal 10 needs at least php 8.1.

Code with deprecations is working code.

Thank you. Yes, you are correct. Even though the deprecations log as errors (versus warnings), the code actually still does work.
